# similar usernames generation in django rest framework

Tags: python, django

I want to generate similar usernames(at least 3) when user given an username that exists in the database that doesn't exist in the database.Even if checking in database existence is not there,but i need  a package to generate similar random names that i can looped for checking existence.Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally make a generator something like so:

```
def get_similar_usernames(username):
    yielded = 0
    n = 0
    existing = User.objects.only("username")
    while yielded < 3:
        potential_username = "{username}{suffix}".format(
            username=username,
            suffix=n
        ))
        for user in existing:
            if user.username == potential_username:
                break
        else:
            yielded += 1
            yield potential_username
        n += 1
```

Usage would be like so:

```
suggested_usernames = [name for name in get_similar_usernames(username)]
```

Of course the precise algorithm to suggest new usernames would be up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply